# MySQL: Default ordering in LIKE queries?

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a MySQL table for users, which looks like this (part of it):

- user_id, user_name, user_password, ...

Now I want to get all users, which contain "foo". I use the following query:

```
SELECT user_id, user_name FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE '%foo%'
```

Question: How are the results of LIKE-queries ordered by default, when I don't have any ORDER BY clause?

Comment: ORDER BY `ASC` according to primary key.

Comment: @FrayneKonok That is not always the case, especially if the records were not put in the table in primary key order

Comment: @RowlandShaw But the order of result come always arrange like ASC order with the primay key.

Comment: @RowlandShaw: It's not ordered by PK for me. User ID results: 20, 2, 17, 7, 8, 19, 14, 13, 21, 23, 27, 8709, 30, ... So is it dependent on insert order?

Comment: @FrayneKonok There is no gaurantee of that, as the poster is seeing.

Comment: @luklapp Per my answer, there is no guarantee of any order unless you specify the `ORDER BY` clause, which is what you're seeing.

Comment: I am not an expert, But what i share is my experience. I got downvote, so i deleted my answer. I have to learn a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no `ORDER BY` clause is specified, then the order is indeterminate.

In the simple case of selecting from a single table, were indexes can't be used (so doing `(column) LIKE '%(something)'` stops the use of any index on column), the results will *tend* to be in table order, which, unless you've manually reordered the table, will be the order they were added to the table.

If an index can be used (e.g doing something like `(column) LIKE '(something)%'` on an indexed column), the result *may* come back in the order of the index.

Adding joins to other tables makes it even more indeterminate, as you're also at the whimsy of any indexes used for the join condition.